# change url structure opencart

Tags: .htaccess, opencart

currently open cart structure is like this

```
(Parent Category URL): ../parent-category
(Sub-Category URL): ../parent-category/sub-category
(Sub-Category Child URL): ../parent-category/sub-category/child-category
(Product URL) : ../product
```

I want it like this

```
(Parent Category URL): ../parent-category
(Sub-Category URL): ../sub-category
(Sub-Category Child URL): ../child-category
(Product URL) : ../parent/product
```

Open cart is php based solution

Comment: Maybe You should use .htaccess rewrite.

Comment: It is not entirely true. You can access the product at these URLs (if the product is attached to more campaigns): `/parent-category/product`, `/parent-category/sub-category/product`, `/parent-category/sub-category/child-category/product` as well as `/product`... And what is the logical reason for this request?

Comment: actually I had that structure in Pinnacle Cart

Answer (score 0):

You can already access your products with or without /parent/ as long as you have your SEO-keyword entered when setting up your product.

Let's say Product A is SEO named "ProductA", and categorized under "Alphabets" with the SEO "ALPHA".

You will be able to access Product A from: website.com/ProductA and website.com/ALPHA/ProductA

You should know this.